# Automate Dynamic Email Send using Salesforce Data without Automation Studio (Basic Edition)

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

In Basic Edition of Marketing Cloud (No Automation Studio) -  Is it possible to:

1. Update a Sendable Data extension based on a Salesforce Report
2. Send an Email Template that references another Data Extension for Email 
   Content using ampscript
3. Happy to use Ampscript or any combination of Lists / Data Extensions that 
   might work

Background - Each Salesforce Contact has a unique identifier associated with it in the Salesforce report (its Parent account unique ID  Not Salesforce ID)
We will use this unique ID to reference a Non Sendable Data Extension in Salesforce to populate email content using ampscript.

Can we use a Salesforce Send to the report and still utilise the Ampsript - can we still use the unique ID to reference the non sendable data extension?

Comment: Are you open to making API calls?

Comment: Hi @Timothy We can make API Calls.

Comment: Where does this report live? In the salesforce core  (as opposed to marketing cloud)? If so, I'm not that familiar with it. Can you make outbound REST calls from there?

Comment: Hi @Timothy, yes it lives in salesforce core and we can make outbound REST calls from Core. However, we have been able to add contact builder, and therefore can now have a synchronised data extension in Marketing Cloud with the relevant contacts in it. What we now need to do is run an SQL query on the synchronised DE (as it is not sendable) and then send to it. So, we no longer now need to send to a Salesforce Report (but still fine to do so if possible) but rather run an SQL query to populate a sendable data extension from a Salesforce Synchronised Data Extension